# How to configure logger format in mix elixir project?

Tags: elixir-mix, elixir

I have an elixir mix project and I am not sure how to configure log format. Below is my configuration:

```
config :logger, backends: [{LoggerFileBackend, :error_log}], format: "$date $time [$level] $levelpad$message\n"
```

what I want is to show `date, time level` in the log file but the log doesn't have `date`:

`15:49:06.384 [info] The Sample is launching: /users/joeyzhao/dev/test1. In space, no one can hear.
15:49:06.384 [info] Elixer version: (1.6.5)
15:49:06.397 [info] Environment
...`

I use below code to log:

`require Logger
...
Logger.info("...")`

Is there anything wrong with my logger config?

Answer (score 0):

That’s the drawback of configuration being loaded *on compilation time*. You have to recompile `logger_file_backend` to reflect changes in your app’s configuration files.